# How to add badges to bottom bar buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a bottom bar with buttons in it. I'm having trouble adding badges to the buttons and tried using the native `.badges` modifier but had no effect.

This is what I'm trying:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Test")
            }
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    ControlGroup {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Button 1", systemImage: "doc")
                                .badge(1)
                        }
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Button 2", systemImage: "checkmark")
                        }
                        .badge(2)
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Button 3", systemImage: "person")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in SwiftUI?

Comment: You are using the wrong type of bar. You should be using `TabBar` not `ToolBar`.

Comment: Thx but no actually I'd like to specifically use the Toolbar not tabs for this design.

Comment: Documentation of `badge` modifier states _"Badges are only displayed in list rows and iOS tab bars"_ . Toolbar is not a Tabbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation of badge modifier states "Badges are only displayed in list rows and iOS tab bars" . Toolbar is not a Tabbar.

A possible approach is to do that in custom way (because toolbar accepts just a view), so it could be like

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
ControlGroup {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Button 1", systemImage: "doc")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Button 2", systemImage: "checkmark")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Button 3", systemImage: "person")
    }
}
.overlay(HStack(alignment: .top) {            // << here !!
    Image(systemName: "1").foregroundColor(.green)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    Image(systemName: "3").foregroundColor(.orange)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    Image(systemName: "9").foregroundColor(.purple)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .symbolVariant(.fill)
    .symbolVariant(.circle)
    .allowsHitTesting(false)
    .offset(x: 10, y: -10)
         // ^^^^ just for demo simplicity, can be somehow dynamic
)
```

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestCustomBadgeOnToolbar.swift)

Comment: Thx for this! Didn't even think the `ControlGroup` could have overlay but worked great. I just had to add `.allowsHitTesting(false)` on the overlay to not interfere with the button taps.